Issues with Cloning and Using eclipse.jdt.ls in IntelliJ IDEA 2024.2
I've cloned the eclipse.jdt.ls repository(https://github.com/eclipse-jdtls/eclipse.jdt.ls) and am trying to use it in IntelliJ IDEA 2024.2.
After selecting "Load Eclipse Project," a popup appeared asking to "Load Maven," which I selected. However, I'm encountering the following issues:
The pom.xml shows an error indicating that org.eclipse.cbi.maven.plugins is not found.
There are multiple errors stating that variables are not found.
Errors appear when trying to import groovy.json.JsonSlurper and groovy.json.JsonOutput.
It seems like the modules are not being recognized properly.
Could anyone guide me on how to resolve these errors or provide the correct setup steps?
Environment:
IntelliJ IDEA 2024.2
Maven
Oracle Open JDK 22
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

eclipse.jdt.ls is Eclipse based which means the dependencies are not specified in the pom.xml, but in the MANIFEST.MF and the target platform. IntelliJ does not support Eclipse based development. You need the Eclipse IDE with PDE, e.g. the Eclipse IDE for Eclipse Committers.
